# Explanation of higher order derivative from Lawrence Perko book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdK2x.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWsSI.jpg)
In the Lawrence Perko differential equations and dynamical systems book Page no 338, Theorem $1$, he introduced the notion $D^2f(x_0,\mu_0)(v,v)$ and $D^3f(x_0,\mu_0)(v,v,v)$. He also directly wrote the values of these quantities in subsequent examples. I have understood the notation $Df(x_0,\mu_0)$ but could not understand the higher orders how this vector $v$ applied? Can someone please explain it in detail

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question should include more details such as you should have to link the particular pages so that we can get details form it.

Comment: I have uploaded the relevant images. Thank you.

Comment: Please make efforts to reduce the image size. Crop whitespace, reduce the resolution and color space to the barely necessary, chose a progressive encoding mode.

Answer (score 0):

$D$ is the differentiation operator in $x$ direction. Thus
\begin{align}
Df(x,\mu)(v)&=\sum_i\frac{∂ f}{∂ x_i}(x,μ)\,v_i\\
D^2f(x,\mu)(v,v)&=\sum_{i,j}\frac{∂^2 f}{∂ x_i∂ x_j}(x,μ)\,v_iv_j\\
D^3f(x,\mu)(v,v,v)&=\sum_{i,j,k}\frac{∂^3 f}{∂ x_i∂ x_j∂ x_k}(x,μ)\,v_iv_jv_k\\
\end{align}
etc.

Comment: Kindly refer page 339 where Example 4 is given. The function f is a vector valued function and hence the above formula given is not applicable as it is a scalar function f and you have given the answer in terms of partial derivatives..

Comment: No, the formula is linear in $f$ and thus also quite valid for vector-valued $f$. Of course you need partial derivatives in multivariate calculus.

Comment: In example 4 can you use the above formula and get the value of $w^T[D^2f(0,0)(v,v)]=-2$. If it is possible please share the calculation here.

Comment: also given that $w^T=v=[1 \quad 0]$

Comment: This is the second derivative of $(w^Tf)$, or in coordinates $\sum_{k,i,j}w_k∂_i∂_jf_k(0)v_iv_j$. I do not have the book, so I do not know what the function and vectors are.